# OSC 8 links not working in the Comint mode

Tags: python, comint, ansi

According to the [NEWS for Emacs 28.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.28.1) (Ctrl-f "OSC 8, for hyperlinks"), the `comint-mode` supports the [OSC 8 styled links](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda). But when I compile (interpret) a file "test.py" with contents,

```python
print(f'\033]8;;{"https://gnu.org"}\033\\{"GNU"}\033]8;;\033\\')
```

Via `(compile "python3 test.py" t)`. I see something like this,

```
^[]8;;https://gnu.org^[\GNU^[]8;;^[\
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of `comint-output-filter-functions`?

Note the specific wording of the Changelog entry:

```
*** Support for OSC escape sequences.
Adding the new function 'comint-osc-process-output' to
'comint-output-filter-functions' enables the interpretation of OSC
("Operating System Command") escape sequences in comint buffers.  By
default, only OSC 8, for hyperlinks, and OSC 7, for directory
tracking, are acted upon.  Adding more entries to
'comint-osc-handlers' allows a customized treatment of further escape
sequences.
```

You have to add `comint-osc-process-output` to the list of hooks in `comint-output-filter-functions` before this feature will operate. You can do this by adding `(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-osc-process-output)` to your init file.